# How to create a resolution "Independent" implementation of Stage for scene2d ui of LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx, imagebutton, scene2d

I have been trying to create a "main menu" screen with a single button.This button however, is 'unclickable' if a Viewport is set for the stage.If the viewport is not set it becomes clickable.The problem with second approach is however that the images "change size" depending on the resolution of devices.So they become smaller on higher resolution devices and vice versa.
Here is the code for your reference:

```
 mainMenu(Game mainGame){
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    menuCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    allVariables.Graphics_viewport_height = (allVariables.Graphics_viewport_width*Gdx.graphics.getHeight())/Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, allVariables.Graphics_viewport_width, allVariables.Graphics_viewport_height);
    camera.update();
    menuCam.setToOrtho(false,allVariables.Graphics_viewport_width,allVariables.Graphics_viewport_height);
    menuCam.update();
    maingame = mainGame;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setViewport(new StretchViewport(allVariables.Graphics_viewport_width,allVariables.Graphics_viewport_height));
    stage.getViewport().setCamera(menuCam);
    table = new Table();
    ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle playButtonStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    playButtonStyle.imageDown =       AllAssets.instance.skin.getDrawable("play_up");
    playButtonStyle.imageUp = AllAssets.instance.skin.getDrawable("play_dn");
    playButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = 10;
    playButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 10;
    play = new ImageButton(playButtonStyle);
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.align(Align.top);
    table.add(play).minSize(100, 200);
    table.debug();
    stage.addActor(table);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);}
```

The resize method :

```
   public void resize(int width, int height) {
         stage.getViewport().update(allVariables.Graphics_viewport_width,allVariables.Graphics_viewport_height,true);
         }
```

What should be done to make it resolution independent so that the button works on different resolutions with same relative size that is not dependent on actual pixels.

Comment: Your resize methods are *completely* incorrect. Are you sure you've read [the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) and understood what viewports are actually doing?

Comment: Thanks.I think now i am confused if I ve understood it at all or not.But to quote from the link "The StretchViewport (source) supports working with a virtual screen size. That means one can assume that a screen is always of the size virtualWidth x virtualHeight. This virtual viewport will then always be stretched to fit the screen. " If i use this why doesnt the image button click?even if in the resize method if I update the viewport using only the virtual size the button does not click!Am i missing something?

Comment: The resize method looks much better now. But you use your virtual resolution only when creating the `StretchViewport`. On resize, you have to update the viewport with the real size (width, height). This will *strech* your virtual resolution to match your actual resolution.

Comment: whoa! SO that means the constructor takes the "world resolution" i.e. the part of the world that needs to be shown and the update method takes the  part of the screen onto which this world needs to be shown! Got it ! let me try and get back.

Comment: Thanks.Problem solved.Though one doubt, for this image button doesnt it change size if we use "setSize" for the imagebutton?Or do i need a 9 patch image only for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this question lies in the fact that there are Two specific size aspects of Viewports in Libgdx.The first is the "part of your game world" you want to show and the second is "the part of your screen" onto which you want to show your world(rather part of your world).
To tell Libgdx the what part of the world you wish to show you can use the constructor of the viewports.Like so:

```
new StretchViewport(worldViewportwidth,worldViewportheight)
```

Now in order to tell Libgdx about which part of your screen (partial part of the screen,full screen,et al) use the update method on the viewport:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
         stage.getViewport().update(width,height,true);
}
```

Now, the stage should be able to accept input (if everything else is also correct) with the stage properly visible on different devices